# How difficult is it to convert a Pathfinder 2nd Edition adventure (or encounter) to 1st Edition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, pathfinder-2e, conversion, encounters

If my gaming group wanted to adapt a Pathfinder 2E AP (e.g. Strength of Thousands), what are the difficulties? We're very familiar with 1E but only lightly so far with 2E.

Is there a reasonable way to adapt encounters to 1E Challenge Ratings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Fairly Challenging

Converting adventures from 2nd Edition to 1st Edition requires a few different things to be replaced, each with their own challenges:

- Replacing creatures/hazards

  - Easy if they already exist in 1E, substantial effort if not (and much more effort at higher levels)
- Replacing treasure

  - Difficult, both systems expect substantial but differing amounts of treasure for characters, and conversion is not straightforward
- Replacing skill/Perception checks

  - Some difficulty in choosing replacements for skills that aren't in 1E like Occultism, but otherwise shouldn't be too hard to keep the DCs roughly equivalent
- Replacing campaign-specific mechanics

  - Highly variant depending on the specifics, something like the academic branches in *Strength of Thousands* would need a complete rework

There is an official free [conversion guide](https://paizo-images.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/image/download/P2e+Conversion+Guide.pdf) for translating content from 1st Edition to 2nd Edition, and some of the content there is helpful when attempting the reverse, particularly for converting items. Note that the *Gamemastery Guide* has since been released, and its sections on building [creatures](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=995) or [hazards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1043) might also be useful for noting comparisons between editions.

### Creatures and Hazards

Building creatures in 1st Edition is a complex process that involves determining multitudes of details that impact each other to combine into the finished product, selecting things like each individual skill rank and Feat depending on the creature's number of hit dice, type, and subtype, to eventually determine its statistics from the ground-up.

Building creatures in 2nd Edition almost entirely consists of pulling numbers off of a table that feel appropriate, deciding their statistics directly based on what you envision. Translating this process back to 1E would take about as much effort as just creating the creature from scratch, with a solid idea in mind for what the result should be.

Probably the best option would be to just modify the adventure to use similarly-leveled creatures that already exist in 1E instead, like using [Ioun wyrds](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ioun%20Wyrd) in place of the [spellskeins](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1616) in *Strength of Thousands*.

Much of the same difficulties and solutions here are shared with hazards, though generally those should be easier to convert because they don't have nearly as many statistics as creatures in 1E.

### Items

The conversion guide linked earlier has a table describing how much an item of a given level in 2nd Edition should cost in 1st Edition, but following that directly will likely skew the player wealth off of the expectation.

In my experience translating the *Strange Aeons* 1E adventure path to 2E, it was best to only convert specific items that already existed or were particularly interesting/plot-relevant and supplement those with additional pieces of treasure where it was originally in the adventure to match the expected treasure per level. [Similar tables](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Placing%20Treasure&Category=Building%20an%20Adventure) exist in 1E, and I'd recommend modifying treasure this way for any converted adventure or encounter.

### Challenge Rating

Level 1 adventurers in 1st Edition would have an average encounter against one CR 1 creature, while those same adventurers in 2nd Edition would have a Low-Threat encounter against a level 2 creature.

Looking at the Encounter Design tables between [1st](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Designing%20Encounters&Category=Building%20an%20Adventure) and [2nd](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=497) Editions, there's actually pretty direct overlap:

- Trivial (40 XP) = Easy (APL - 1)
- Low (60 XP) = Average (APL)
- Moderate (80 XP) = Challenging (APL + 1)
- Severe (120 XP) = Hard (APL + 2)
- Extreme (160 XP) = Epic (APL + 3)

Both have the same property that increasing the value by 2 (Level/CR 1 => Level/CR 3) results in getting twice as much XP for the encounter.

Answer (score 14):

### Quite simply, “convert” doesn’t describe this process

You are, instead, writing your own 1e adventure inspired by the 2e one. All mechanical details in the 2e adventure are basically useless to you, and some of the narrative ones may well require tweaking too.

This is because the two systems are **wildly** different. Larger, even, than the difference between WotC D&D editions, which is already a massive gap. There is no meaningful relationship between a given level in 1e and the same level in 2e, no function *f* such that *f*(*CR*<sub>2e</sub>) = *CR*<sub>1e</sub>.

Pathfinder 2e has a lot going for it. Pathbuilder is a pretty phenomenal utility for making characters, making it way easier to try out. Particularly since you aren’t looking to hang on to existing 1e characters—you only mention familiarity with 1e, rather than an ongoing 1e campaign, as your motivation—you are likely **far** better off just playing the adventure in 2e.